# Should I worry about high ssd temperature?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, temperature, samsung-ssd

I am using a new ssd and I installed CrystalDiskInfo, it shows good as health status but the temperature is very high it is 95 degree C. Should I worry about that and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

SSD cooling is an interesting problem. There are two kinds of chips in an SSD: the controller and memory chips. While the controller shouldn't be too hot, the memory chips counter-intuitively prefer high temperatures: when the module is hot, the flash degrades less during writes.

Some motherboards come with radiators on the M.2 slots. They usually do no harm, but interestingly enough, some of these radiators [make SSDs run hotter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIkWnnDjhkk).

I'd assume this temperature is fine. Unless your SSD comes with additional cooling solution, you don't need one.

Comment: Got a source for that? And also, IF less degradation during writing, what does temp do for degradation while data just sits?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Sorry, I've read about it way too long ago to remember. I think the linked videos was one of the sources. As for your other question, I'd assume not much as long as it's within spec.

Answer (score 3):

From: [What’s A Safe Operating Temperature For SSDs?](https://harddrivegeek.com/ssd-temperature/)

> Most SSDs are rated for running within a temperature range of 0ºC up
> to a max temp of 70ºC (32ºF to 158ºF). This range is about the same
> for every consumer SSD currently on the market, but can sometimes vary
> slightly based on the model and form factor of the SSD (2.5” SATA, M.2
> or mSATA) – but a drive under 70ºC is generally within the operating
> parameters provided by SSD manufacturers.
>
> However, studies like the one [Facebook](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/facebook-study-finds-no-correlation-between-ssd-reads-and-failure-rate/) conducted in their own
> data centers found that the hotter your SSD runs, the quicker it wears
> out the flash memory inside of the drive. So while an SSD can
> technically operate at the higher ranges advertised by manufacturers,
> you’re going to get better data integrity and more life out of your
> SSD if you keep it cool.
>
> If the SSD inside of your desktop is running hot make sure that you
> have it mounted in a spot with sufficient airflow. A lot of cases have
> SSD mounts located in low airflow spots like behind the motherboard or
> between other warm components like hard drives. If you can, try to
> move your SSD to a spot in the case where it can breathe. Try to make
> sure that the drive has air blowing over it when your machine is
> running.
>
> If your SSD is running hot inside of an external enclosure you may
> want to consider a different enclosure, such as one made of metal to
> better conduct heat away from the drive. You can also use a simple
> SATA to USB adapter which allows you to run your SSD completely naked
> (without a case), but I wouldn’t recommend going without an enclosure
> if you’re planning on tossing the drive in a bag to take with you.
>
> If your SSD is getting hot inside your laptop you don’t have a lot you
> can do. Other nearby components such as the battery, ram, or the CPU
> may be getting a bit too hot and heating up the entire system. If your
> laptop SSD is constantly running hot you probably want to call the
> support line for whoever makes your laptop and see if they have any
> suggestions about the high temps.

Comment: The conclusion of this website regarding the Facebook study is wrong. Their results were completely inconsistent. Some scenarios with permanently throttling SSDs.because of high temps have the same low failure rate than the coolest scenarios. I would say it's completely random.

Answer (score 0):

Install Intel MAS software on Intel cpu boards. It worked or me as I have an intel optane nvme stick.

Update ssd firmware.

If above two donot work try cooling solutions. On laptop Copper heatsinks can help.
Increase air flow, with cooling fan base for laptops.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is exceptionally difficult to add cooling solutions to laptops, and OP doesnt' mention laptops. What is Intel MAS software and how does it solve this problem?