How to prevent SSD getting hot
I have a windows 11 laptop with m.2 SSD. And my SSD gets hot. Approximately 53C degrees on idle. This heat makes it uncomfortable to have the laptop on my lap. Is there a way to make it run cooler?

Without the laptop and SSD model, nothing can be said for sure. SSDs get extremely hot when under heavy load, such as large file transfers, but should reside ~40C or less when not under load. It could be poorly designed SSD port placement, a bottom laptop casing not thick enough above the SSD, poor cooling management for that area of the motherboard, etc. Much the same as it is with gaming laptops that put out a lot of heat, a laptop lap holder may be required since our clothes/legs create hotpots when a laptop is placed on them due to infrared and lack of quality airflow

Why worry?? See https://superuser.com/questions/1592187/should-i-worry-about-high-ssd-temperature

my solution was to put an appropriately sized cutting board under the laptop. that keeps its belly clear for airflow, and puts somthing between me and the laptop.

Do you know that it is the SSD that is generating all this heat? CPUs and GPUs are generally more likely to produce lots of heat under load, though SSDs could be a factor. Does the laptop have adequate airflow when it is on your lap (eg, are your legs/clothes blocking some of the airflow)? Do you know if the laptop design includes any consideration for cooling the SSD like access to a nearby heat pipe, or a heat spreader or cooling fins?

I found a way but it makes the laptop very slow and less responsive.
Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings
Change advanced power settings\PCI Express\Link State Power Management

Selecting maximum power savings makes the ssd run cooler. Approximately 40C in my case.
